# Extracting Binance Futures Data with Python (ETHUSDT Quarterly 0625)

Tags: python, api, binance

I am trying to extract price information: "ETHUSDT Quarterly 0625" from Binance using the Python API.

I am able to extract ETHUSDT data using:
https://www.binance.com/en/futures/ethusdt

```
symbol = "ETHUSDT"

# get timestamp of earliest date data is available
timestamp = client._get_earliest_valid_timestamp(symbol, '1d')

# request historical candle (or klines) data
bars = client.get_historical_klines(symbol, '1d', timestamp, limit=500)
```

However when I change symbol to "ETHUSDT Quarterly 0625" It will not work, I have looked everywhere for the symbol for the quarterly future data but I cannot find the symbol.
https://www.binance.com/en/futures/ethusdt_quarter

```
symbol = "ETHUSDT Quarterly 0625"

# get timestamp of earliest date data is available
timestamp = client._get_earliest_valid_timestamp(symbol, '1d')

# request historical candle (or klines) data
bars = client.get_historical_klines(symbol, '1d', timestamp, limit=500)
```

I have tried many many possible combinations of the symbol to make it work but it won't
Does anyone know how to either get the futures quarterly data another way? or know the symbol. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions `get_historical_klines` this will only give data of spot market.
There is also a function `get_futures_historical_klines` this will give you what you are looking for. Also please check out the documentation as this varies of futures and coin. Also the **symbol structure works differently on API rather than on exchange**.

Try `get_tickers()` or `get_futures_tickers()` to get available symbols

Comment: Thank you, I found the documentation for  get_futures_historical_klines at 
https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=get_futures_historical_klines#binance.client.Client.futures_historical_klines

But I am unable to find get_futures_tickers() on the documentation, how do I make use of this function to get the ETHUSDT futures symbol?

Comment: client.futures_ticker()